# Java 8 stream combine two different collections

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm still new to java 8 streams so I'm figuring out how to do it at simplest as possible.

I would like to know if there is simpler solution for combining two streams of different objects.

Let's say I have following java objects.

```
public class Message {

    private String id;
    private String key;
    private List<MessageLocalization> localizations = new ArrayList<>();

    // ...getters setters
}

public class MessageLocalization {

    private String id;
    private String language;
    private String baseText;
    private String shortText;
    private String longText;
    private Integer orderBy = 1;

    // ...getters setters
}
```

and with following method I'm retrieving all messages with their localizations.

```
public List<Message> getAllMessages() {
        List<Message> messages =
                StreamSupport
                        .stream(messageRepository.findAll().spliterator(), false)
                        .map(message -> new Message(message.getId(), message.getMessageKey()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

        messages
                .stream()
                .forEach(message -> {
                    localizationRepository.findAllByObjectIdAndLocalizedType(message.getId(), LocalizedType.MESSAGE)
                            .stream()
                            .forEach(localization -> {
                                message.getLocalizations().add(
                                        new MessageLocalization(localization.getId(),
                                                localization.getLanguage(),
                                                localization.getBaseText(),
                                                localization.getShortText(),
                                                localization.getLongText(),
                                                localization.getOrderBy()));
                            });
                });
}
```

So here I have two steps:

1. retrieving data from repository and constructing `Message` list
2. streaming `Message` list and retrieving data from other repository for its localizations

Can this be rewritten somehow simpler (for example include the second step in first one)?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: basically you are asking about improving existing, working code. That could also go to codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the initialization of the `localizations` list as part of the `Message` object’s initialization:

```
public List<Message> getAllMessages() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(messageRepository.findAll().spliterator(), false)
        .map(message -> {
            Message newMessage = new Message(message.getId(), message.getMessageKey());
            localizationRepository.findAllByObjectIdAndLocalizedType(message.getId(), LocalizedType.MESSAGE)
                .forEach(localization -> {
                    newMessage.getLocalizations().add(
                        new MessageLocalization(localization.getId(),
                            localization.getLanguage(),
                            localization.getBaseText(),
                            localization.getShortText(),
                            localization.getLongText(),
                            localization.getOrderBy()));
            });
            return newMessage;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This naturally leads to the conclusion that the code could be even simpler if the `Message` constructor would accept a list of localizations…

Comment: The `Message` constructor recommendation would make it a lot simpler +1

Comment: That's very nice. @arizzle what do you mean by Message constructor recommendation?

Comment: If there were two arrays in Message (for example List<Category>) is there a possibility to process each collection paralelly? I mean List< MessageLocalization>  and  List<Category> paralelly.

Comment: @bilak: you can construct a `List<MessageLocalization>` without an actual `Message` instance as you only need the already known ID. So, if `Message` had a constructor accepting such a pre-built list instead of needing `getLocalizations().add(…)` steps, you could simplify the code, as it would eliminate the need for a local variable, in turn eliminating the need for a block lambda, i.e. `.map(message -> new Message(message.getId(), message.getMessageKey(), /* localization list creation code*/))`

Comment: You can parallelize fetching two of these lists, but not as a Stream operation, as Stream don’t parallelize in that direction. This would be more of a `CompletableFuture` task, which you could embed in the `Message` initialization step.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to to @Holger I've finished with this construction (maybe this will be useful for someone in future)

```
List<Message> messages = StreamSupport.stream(messageRepository.findAll().spliterator(), false)
                .map(message -> new Message(message.getId(),
                        message.getMessageKey(),
                        // list localizations
                        StreamSupport
                                .stream(localizationRepository.findAllByObjectIdAndLocalizedType(message.getId(), LocalizedType.MESSAGE).spliterator(),
                                        false)
                                .map(localization -> new MessageLocalization(localization.getId(),
                                        localization.getLanguage(),
                                        localization.getBaseText(),
                                        localization.getShortText(),
                                        localization.getLongText(),
                                        localization.getOrderBy()))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList()),
                        // list categories
                        StreamSupport.stream(messageCategoryRepository.findAllByMessageId(message.getId()).spliterator(), false)
                                .map(msgCategory -> new MessageCategory(msgCategory.getId(), msgCategory.getMessageId(), msgCategory.getCategoryId()))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())

                )).collect(Collectors.toList());
```